# Можно ли читать параллельно в нескольких процессах/потоках из одной партиции Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

У меня есть кластер и топики с 3 партициями. По умолчанию когда я забираю батч из кафки, я сдигаю оффсет после прочтения всех сообщений. Могу ли я параллельно читать в нескольких потоках из этой партиции?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Партиции в Кафке -- это и есть единица параллелизма. Все сообщения из партиции обычно читаются последовательно. Насколько я знаю, так работают все официальные драйверы.

В приложении же вы можете прочитать последовательно N сообщений (это очень быстро), а потом распараллелить их обработку. Однако при этом вам нужно будет подумать, когда и что коммитить, что делать с сообщениями, которые не удалось обработать и т.д.